# Custom action to pass command line argurments to a exe

Tags: wix, custom-action

I'm using Wix installer in which i use custom action to execute my exe(windows form) with command line arguments. I tried the following way in order to execute my custom action.

```
<CustomAction Id="ConnMgrCACmd" Property="ConnMgrCAWithProperty"
          Value="&quot;[#ConnectionManagerExe.exe]&quot; /COMMAND=ADD FILEPATH="[INSTALLDIR]" KEY="[DB_KEY]" Execute="immediate"/>
<CustomAction Id="ConnMgrCAWithProperty" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec"
          Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no"/>
```

But the above code is not working for me. Is my custom action is right?.

Comment: I suppose you should do extra quotes escaping around `[INSTALLDIR]` and `[DB_KEY]`

Comment: Yeah I tried it is working. Could you tell me how to hide the console(.exe)?

Comment: well, actually this is what `CAQuietExec` is for - it should hide the console window...

Comment: It seems my custom action is not able to pass the command line parameters to the exe. It worked for while but after that custom action failed and exit from the installer. Here is my complete code.

<CustomAction Id="ConnMgrCACmd" Property="ConnMgrCAWithProperty"
          Value="&quot;[#ConnectionManagerExe.exe]&quot; /COMMAND=ADD FILEPATH=[INSTALLDIR] KEY=[DB_KEY] Execute="immediate"/>
<CustomAction Id="ConnMgrCAWithProperty" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec"
          Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no"/>

Comment: I can see you removed the quotes around INSTALLDIR, but if it contains spaces, this won't work. You'd rather escape those, the way you do for .exe itself, using &quot;

Comment: My INSTALLDIR value would be like C:\Program Files\Product Name. I tried to put like this
FILEPATH=&quot;[INSTALLDIR]&quot; but not working. Any Idea?

Comment: INSTALLDIR value should be look like "C:\Program Files\ Product Name"

Comment: Execute msi from command prompt with log and then search in the log for the custom action name. Log will provide the parameter names. then we can check where quotes are missing and then add them

Comment: Atlast it got worked. Thank you very much.